# Transforming json data list field to columns with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mariadb

Currently I have in my DB(mariaDB) a column that is called data and contains a json list:

```
ID   | data
1    | '["section1","section2","section3"]'
2    | '["section2","section4"]'
```

I would like to turn it into something like that:

```
id   | section1     | section2     | section3         | section4
1    | 1            | 1            | 1                | 0
2    | 0            | 1            | 0                | 1
```

Meaning that all possible values from all fields become columns and get the value `1` if that list item exists for the row accordingly and `0` if it does not.

Is there any way to transform this with a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT 
    id, 
    JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(data, 'all', 'section1')) section1, 
    JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(data, 'all', 'section2')) section2, 
    JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(data, 'all', 'section3')) section3, 
    JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(data, 'all', 'section4')) section4 
from test;
```

If you need zeros instead of NULLs then wrap the expressions with COALESCE().

If separate `data` value cannot contain duplicated values (and this is provided by according constraint) or if you need not values amount but their presence only you may use

```sql
select 
    id, 
    JSON_CONTAINS(data, '"section1"') section1, 
    JSON_CONTAINS(data, '"section2"') section2, 
    JSON_CONTAINS(data, '"section3"') section3, 
    JSON_CONTAINS(data, '"section4"') section4 
from test;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=3595289deed8f537b573006a303a043a)

PS. If the list of possible `sectionX` values is indefinite or dynamic then you must use stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
select 
    id, 
    data ->> '$[0]' section1, 
    data ->> '$[1]' section2, 
    data ->> '$[2]' section3, 
    data ->> '$[3]' section4 
from mytable
```

Or using `json_extract()`:

```
select 
    id, 
    json_unqote(json_extract(data, '$[0]')) section1, 
    json_unqote(json_extract(data, '$[1]')) section2, 
    json_unqote(json_extract(data, '$[2]')) section3, 
    json_unqote(json_extract(data, '$[3]')) section4 
from mytable
```

Comment: Query 1 - MariaDB does not support `->` and `->>` operators; Query 2 - you pivot posessionally, not by the value. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=81a210538cd7c4012bed3cb99d99cf43)